# Why isn't my HTTP.call() to POST to a php file not working as desired?

Tags: php, meteor, xmlhttprequest

How do I correctly use Meteor `HTTP.call()` to POST the contents of a form to a PHP file for further processing?

My current code (*server/main.js*) uses `HTTP.call()` to POST to a remote PHP page, but returns an error message that isn't humanly readable.

Find below what the returned error message looks like in the terminal:

[image: The error message I get in the Terminal after HTTP.call() Posting]

The desired response should look more like this:

[image: The desired response from the HTTP.call()]

Below is what my remote PHP file (*http://2117c3a8.ngrok.io/TalkGateLane/escrow/c2b.php*) looks like:

```
<?
    require_once "TalkGateLane.php";

    //Specify your credentials
    $username = "DrOctogon";
    $apiKey   = "1c1f0df78c3b";

    $gateway = new TalkGateLane($username, $apiKey, "sandbox");

    $productName = "pesa";
    // The 3-Letter ISO currency code for the checkout amount

    // Provide the details of a mobile money recipient
    $recipient = array(
        "phoneNumber" => $_POST['recipient'],
        "currencyCode" => "KES",
        "amount" => $_POST['amount'],
        "metadata" => array(
            "name" => "Something...",
            "reason" => "Som other thing..."
        )
    );

    $phoneNumber  = $_POST['payer'];
    $currencyCode = "KES";
    $amount       = $_POST['amount'];
    $metadata     = array(
        "name" => "Something...",
        "reason" => "Som other thing..."
    );


    try {
        $transactionId = $gateway->initiateMobilePaymentCheckout($productName, $phoneNumber, $currencyCode, $amount, $metadata);
        $msg           = 'The payment of ' . $currencyCode . ' ' . $amount . ' has been sent your account';

        $gateway->sendMessage($_POST['recipient'] . ',' . $_POST['payer'], $msg);
        echo $msg;
    }
    catch (AfricasTalkingGatewayException $e) {
        echo "Received error response: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Following (in the *server/main.js*) is what my `HTTP.call()` looks like:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'c2b': function(recipientsNumber, recipientsAmount, payer) {

        console.log("recipientsNumber: " + recipientsNumber);
        console.log("recipientsAmount: " + recipientsAmount);
        console.log("payer: " + payer);

        var postData = {
            params: {

                "payer": payer,
                "recipient": recipientsNumber,
                "amount": recipientsAmount
            }
        }

        HTTP.call('POST', 'http://2117c3a8.ngrok.io/TalkGateLane/escrow/c2b.php', {
                headers: {
                    apiKey: '1c1f0df78c3b'
                },
                params: postData
            },

            function(error, response) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                if (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            }
        );

    }
});
```

Comment: I would guess it is because your `postData` is an object with a `params` property, and you are sending it as `params`, so you are sending a nested `params` object to the `call` method.

Comment: @MasterAM kindly elaborate how it should be in code if possible.

Comment: Simply have the `postData`  variable to the content of `params`. `var postData = { payer: ...};`

Comment: @MasterAM Ooh thanks man! Your advise worked!